# show sales report to pass the parameter like month,date to Magento Soap api

Tags: magento, soap

I am fetching sales report from Magento store to use SOAP API. This is working fine but this show all Sales Report. I want custom report like to pass the Specific Month or Date.
How this can be possible my code is as follow.

```
  $mage_url = 'https://domain.com/index.php/api/soap/index/wsdl/1'; 
  $mage_user = 'Mohammad'; 
  $mage_api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 

  // Initialize the SOAP client 
   $soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 

  // Login to Magento 
  $session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );

 // Start a session to make API requests
 $resources = $soap->resources( $session_id );
 $products = $soap->call($session_id, 'sales_order.list');
```

This is also so useful for the developers

Answer (score 0):

For Completed orders

```
   $products = $soap->call($session_id, 'sales_order.list', array(array('status'=>array('eq'=>'complete'))));
```

For Specific Period

```
 $thedate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("1 month ago"));
 $thesearch =array(array('updated_at'=>array('from'=>"$thedate"), 'status'=>array('eq'=>"complete")));
 $products = $soap->call($session_id, 'sales_order.list', $thesearch);
```

Working fine